# count by name the number of all values, within a given DB SQL column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB column named "quality" with about 10,000 records. records were fetched from different sources so I'm trying to create a map that will rename them into just a few values.

To do this, I first need to understand how many values do I have and with what names.

With what command can I get a results table like this, from most common to less:

```
1549: Excellent
1500: Poor
1400: Great
1394: Awesome
```

And so on.. should some to 10,000

Comment: Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Give us your sample data with the corresponding result, Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the values using `group by`:

```
select quality, count(*)
from t
group by quality
order by count(*) desc;
```

You can then assign a word or phrase using a `case` expression.  That logic is not clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH grades AS ( SELECT 1550 points_from, 100000 points_to, 'Excellent' grade
                 UNION ALL SELECT 1500, 1550, 'Good'
                 UNION ALL SELECT 1400, 1500, 'So-so'
                 UNION ALL SELECT 0, 1400, 'Poor' )
SELECT source_table.*, grades.grade
FROM source_table
JOIN grades ON source_table.points >= grades.points_from
           AND source_table.points < grades.points_to
```

and

```
WITH grades AS ( SELECT 1550 points_from, 100000 points_to, 'Excellent' grade
                 UNION ALL SELECT 1500, 1550, 'Good'
                 UNION ALL SELECT 1400, 1500, 'So-so'
                 UNION ALL SELECT 0, 1400, 'Poor' )
SELECT grades.grade, COUNT(source_table.id) `count`
FROM source_table
JOIN grades ON source_table.points >= grades.points_from
           AND source_table.points < grades.points_to
GROUP BY grades.grade
```

Of course it's better when the relation between points and grades is stored in static table.